# mod_rewrite rule for drupal works except homepage/root domain

Tags: drupal, mod-rewrite

I have a pretty simple rewrite rule to redirect mobile agents to our mobile domain from our drupal 6 multisites

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/vnd.wap.wml [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(ipad|joojoo|tablet|hiton) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
# Param in URL to skip going to mobile site
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !mobile=1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} \bagent1|agent2|agent3etc..\b [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) "http\:\/\/m\.domain\.com/" [R=301,L]
```

Everything with the above is working great EXCEPT the home page, whenever I goto www.domain.com or domain.com or even www.domain.com/, I do not get redirected. Any other page on the site works fine. I've tried using rewritebase / with the same results. Any suggestions?

TIA

Comment: I have no idea why, but the problem was directories. I removed RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d and it works, with it, it doesn't. Strange because the default drupal rules comes next and it does have that condition.

Comment: But that's what I say in my answer 7 hours before. Don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

> Everything with the above is working great EXCEPT the home page, whenever I goto  `www.domain.com` or `domain.com` or even `www.domain.com/`

I guess you need another rule without the REQUEST_FILENAME conditions and with one additional condition to confirm the URI-path is empty.

Since conditions are only valid for the next rule, it is necessary to repeat them for this additional rule. You may try inserting this block of code above the one in your question:

```
# Conditions in the question
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/vnd.wap.wml [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(ipad|joojoo|tablet|hiton) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !mobile=1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} \bagent1|agent2|agent3etc..\b [NC]

# New condition and rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$       [NC]
RewriteRule ^   http://m.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

NOTE: Your current rule could be improved, as the substitution URL is a plain text string. Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://m.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Faa, I ultimately went that route and when it still didn't work I just duplicated the rule set after and started removing things one by one until it turned out to by the directory condition (see above)

Comment: That's exactly what I point out in my answer: "**...without the REQUEST_FILENAME conditions...**". The `!-d` condition excludes the root directory from the rule. On the other hand, you can't just remove that condition from the current code, you will have problems with requests to existing directories. They wont be excluded from the rule and something will break in your site. The way to do it, is as indicated in my answer: **Adding** the block of code to the one in your question. By block of code I mean the whole set of rules in my answer (11 lines or so).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to use mobile tools module. It works for all!